how to fix the duplicate data issue?
My code is here.
KMB.jsx
import BusStopTable from './BusStopTable';
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary';
import { Suspense } from 'react';

export default function KMB() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Suspense fallback={<h2> Loading...</h2>}>
        <BusStopTable />
      </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}

The BusStopTable component fetches the bus stop list for a route from a REST API.
BusStopTable.jsx
import BusStop from "./BusStop";
import fetchBusStopListByRoute from "./fetchBusStopListByRoute";
export default function BusStopTable() {
  //let data = fetchData(8).read();
  //https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/route-stop/${route}/1`);
  let busStopList = fetchBusStopListByRoute(8).read();
  return (
    <div>
      { 
        busStopList.data.map(busStop=>(
          <div key={busStop.stop}>
            <BusStop stopId={busStop.stop}/>
          </div>  
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

Because the bus stop list only contains bus stop ID, I need to fetch the bus stop info in the BusStop component from another REST API to display the bus stop name.
Unfortunately, the BusStop component shows the duplicate bus stop name.
BusStop.jsx
import fetchBusStopInfo from "./fetchBusStopInfo";
export default function BusStop({stopId}){
  let busStopInfo=fetchBusStopInfo(stopId).read();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(busStopInfo));
  return <div>{stopId},{busStopInfo.data.name_en}</div>
}

fetchBusStopInfo.js
import axios from 'axios';
let result;
let status = "pending";
export default function fetchBusStopInfo(stopId) {
  let api = axios.create();
  api.interceptors.response.use(
    null, // default success handler
    (error) => {
      console.log(error.toJSON());
      return Promise.reject({
        status: error.response?.status,
        message:
          error.response?.data ?? error.response?.statusText ?? error.message,
      });
    }
  );
  let suspender = api({
    url: `https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/stop/${stopId}`,
    method: 'get',
  }).then(
    (r) => {
      //console.log('r', r,status);
      status = 'success';
      result = r.data;
    },
    (e) => {
      status = 'error';
      result = e;
    }
  );
  function read() {
    //console.log("hi",status,result);
    if (status === 'pending') {
      throw suspender;
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      throw result;
    } else if (status === 'success') {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return {
    read: read,
  };
}

fetchBusStopListByRoute.js
import axios from 'axios';
let result;
let status = "pending";
export default function fetchBusStopListByRoute(route){
  let api = axios.create();
  api.interceptors.response.use(
    null, // default success handler
    (error) => {
      console.log(error.toJSON());
      return Promise.reject({
        status: error.response?.status,
        message:
          error.response?.data ?? error.response?.statusText ?? error.message,
      });
    }
  );
  let suspender=api({
    url: `https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/route-stop/${route}/inbound/1`,
    method: 'get',
  }).then(
    (r) => {
      //console.log('r', r,status);
      status = 'success';
      result = r.data;
    },
    (e) => {
      status = 'error';
      result = e;
    }
  );
  function read(){
    //console.log("hi",status,result);
    if (status === 'pending') {
      throw suspender;
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      throw result;
    } else if (status === 'success') {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return {
    "read":read
  };
};

How can I fix the problem?

This isn't how you fetch data in React components. Please see https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

It makes the Suspense component not working.

Right, and React doesn't provide anything out-of-the-box... "Suspense-enabled data fetching without the use of an opinionated framework is not yet supported. The requirements for implementing a Suspense-enabled data source are unstable and undocumented. ". I'd be more inclined to do all the data fetching as one async operation and pass fully hydrated objects to your BusStop component
